# android app disk usage

Tags: android

Is there API to get the disk usage of an android application by package name? I think the disk usage is size of data in /data/data/ folder. The API may look like:

`int getDiskUsage(String packageName)`

Could someone help, thanks!

Comment: I'd personally consider the total usage to include the apk file itself, typically under /data/app, in addition to the extracted and created files typically under /data/data

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the PackageStats class (for instance, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageStats.html)).